# Routing in rails - When to route to a crud method and when to route with the given parameter

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, routes

I am in need of a little help regarding routing in rails. Traditionally if I have a route in routes.rb

> resources:categories

it will match www.website.com/categories/id were id is an integer. But what happens if I wanted to route to a specific user or category like so:

> www.example.com/categories/apple

instead of the traditional:

> www.example.com/categories/4

I currently have these two lines in my routes.rb

> match 'categories/:name' => 'categories#show'
>
> resources :categories

so www.example.com/categories/apple will route to the show method in the categories controller correctly.

**but**

What if I want to create a new category? Here's the problem

> www.example.com/categories/new

will route to the **show** method, and will not route to the **new** method

I can place an if statement in the show method checking is params[:name] == new, but I feel that there must be a better way to solve this problem.

My end goal is to route based on the string of the category (apple) and not based on it's ID (4) but also be able to create, update, and destroy a category.

Any tips?

Thanks!

Comment: Have you considered using a Gem like [FriendlyId](https://github.com/norman/friendly_id/#friendlyid)?

Answer (score 0):

you can pass a name as a parameter, for example you can try

`link_to category_path(category.name)` instead of `link_to category_path(category)`

and it will go to categories#show in controller, the route will look like example.com/categories/categoryName, in the show action of your cateogries controller, params[:id] will have the name, you'll need something like

`Category.find_by_name params[:id]` instead of `Category.find params[:id]`

Hope this helps you.

Answer (score 0):

As @pdoherty926 says in the comment, you could use FriendlyId. If you want to manage it manually, you don't have to overwrite the routes, just put the needed code in the `:show` action:

```
class CategoriesControllers < ...
  ...

  def show
    if /^\d+$/ =~ params[:id]
      # ... normal workflow for integer id
    elsif /soe_regexp_that_matches_names>/
      # ... do your thing with names
    else
      raise 404
    end
  end

  ...
end
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the most simple way to do this your way is to define a route before your

```
match 'categories/:name' => 'categories#show'
```

like this:

```
match 'categories/new' => 'categories#new'

match 'categories/:name' => 'categories#show'
```

the order matters.

Comment: afaik, match is deprecated in rails 4 and replaced by the corresponding verb(in this case 'get')

Comment: @RobinR.Winton: shure, but i don't know the rails version and the example uses `match`. So I guessed, it would be another rails version. If there's a hint in the code pointing to rails 4. I missed it :)